# Finding unique characters in words with RegEx

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to use RegEx to match characters in a sequence that only appear one time within that word. So for example in `armored armadillo` the only matches would be `e`, `i` and  .

My first attempt was to use lookaround to match characters such that no copy of the same character appeared before or after the match:

`(.)(?<!^.*\1)(?!\1.*$)`

But this appears to match no characters no matter what I do. What am I doing wrong? How can I match characters in the way that I want to?

Comment: I think a regular expression is the wrong tool for this problem.

Comment: Maybe, but the goal is mostly didactic here - I am trying to learn RegEx so I am forcing myself to solve issues with it even if I already know how to address them in other ways

Comment: You may want to call this out in the future, because this web site focuses on *practical* solutions, not didactic ones. (Says so [in big print the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour): "Get answers to practical, detailed questions".)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```js
(.)(?<!\1.+)(?!.*\1)
```

The regex captures a char into Group 1 and then makes sure there is no such char before and after with the two lookarounds.

To match any chars including line breaks replace `.` with `[\s\S]` or prepend the pattern with `(?s)` inline modifier (`(?m)` in Ruby).

*Details*

- `(.)` - Group 1: any single char (other than line break char by default)
- `(?<!\1.+)` - a negative lookbehind that fails the match if there is Group 1 value followed by one or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible immediately to the left of the current position (`+` is required here to make sure `.` matches at least one char, the one that was captured into Group 1)
- `(?!.*\1)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there are zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible and then Group 1 value immediately to the right of the current position.

See [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FHVNXf/1).

Comment: Interesting. Why is the `+` needed in the negative lookbehind? Is it so it doesn't register a negative by comparing the reference to itself?

Comment: @TheRedMage I added the explanation.